# Sending bulk mail

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, spf

I currently have a system which sends bulk mail through user's own mail server using swiftmailer in php, Everything works 100% on that side, but I recently started tracking bounce backs by setting up my own hmailserver with a bounce address and setting the return-path for all outgoing mails to a mail account on that server where a script updates the DB, this too works 100%.

The only issue I am having is the SPF record for my own mail server is very strict and MTA's block mail sent by users from their own servers with my bounce account as the return-path because the SPF fails.

I posted a question on serverfault when it started and someone explained to me that it is not the mail header that is used by spf but the the SMTP envelope.

Basically my question is for better deliverability, would it be better to send all mail from my own mail server and set the reply-to mail address to the users mail account, or should I spoof the from mail header, or am I taking the wrong approach and there is a simpler way?

Comment: Simplest and most reliable option is to use a service who's job is specifically to do this exact thing.

Comment: why would someone downvote, there is a lot of research as it is already a working solution and the question is not unclear it's basically an A or B question about improving mail deliverability which I left open to other suggestions if you feel A or B is not the correct option, also I don't charge money for this so using something like mandrilla is not an option.

Comment: While I didn't downvote, I can understand people that did given this isn't a programming question.

Comment: The people at server fault said this isn't a server question but a programming question, because it is about system design and not server interpretation, but I got a great idea from one of the guys there so got a solution thanks for your trouble, and sorry I got annoyed just though that this sight was about collaborating on all aspects of programming but that's my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have been me that suggested that. Forging the from address is a good way to get bounced for SPF failure; reply-to is the way to go. Use VERP addressing for your bounce handling to ensure you can tell what address the original message was sent to (you can't always tell otherwise, thanks to Exchange being useless). Otherwise I agree with henry's answer - getting your SPF included solves a lot of problems, it's what I do at smartmessages.net when possible, so you might find [our docs on SPF](https://wiki.smartmessages.net/#SPF) useful. I'd also recommend looking into DKIM and DMARC, though DKIM is quite hairy to implement yourself.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for all your help, I already have DKIM implemented, but because an external server sends the mail both DKIM and SPF would fail and that would cause DMARC to fail. So ideally I should have the users add my server address to their SPF records and send all mail from my own server forging the FROM address?

Comment: It's the SPF that determines what is a forgery, so if you are included in their record, you're no longer forging.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why you want to send mail on your own and not use a mail service to save money. The only issue with setting the "Reply-To" field is some mail clients don't recognize it and they will still be responding on the 5322.FROM field.  But why not just ask your clients to set the "SPF" to include your SPF record in their DNS. That's what other email marketing programs do, it's a little bit more of a hassle.  Just provide them a semi technical resource about a [SPF Record](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/spfrecords/) and point them to an [SPF Wizard](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/) and tell them to add an `include:<your spf record>` in the wizard. Then provide instructions from their DNS provider on how to add that record. And I +1 your question, because it's a good question, but it's not about programming, but I believe belongs more on serverfault, not sure why they told you otherwise.